# Use JavaScript to Randomly Select Images for HTML Background Tiles

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background-image

I am programming a game in HTML/CSS/JavaScript and I currently have the background set to a single image (100px / 100px) being repeated vertically and horizontally to tile across the whole body of the page;

CSS:

```html
body {
    background-image: url("./assets/bgImage.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

That's fine and it works exactly as you would expect it to.

My question is whether or not it's possible to have an array of images to choose from and have each (quote unquote) "execution" of CSS' repeating of the background image randomly (or procedurally) select one of the images from the array to fill into the "slot" that the next repetition would fulfill.  And if this is possible, how would one go about accomplishing that?  The desired result would look something like this (obviously without the margins);

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

The only way I can think of to accomplish this would be to use `<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1;">` and then auto populate it with my own generated array of images.  While that's possible and I know I *could* do it that way, I'd like to make sure there isn't a simpler and more effective way to accomplish this first.

Comment: Better write a browser-game by using `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty solution. I've used an `canvas` element and your images.

**ES6:**

```js
class GenerateMap {

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    // canvas
    self.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    self.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const TILE_WIDTH = 100;
    const TILE_HEIGHT = 100;

    const CANVAS_WIDTH = 500;
    const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 500;

    self.canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    self.canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

    let xAxes = 0;
    let yAxes = 0;
    let lineCount = 0;

    // existing tiles
    self.tiles = [{
      url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwkth.png'
    }, {
      url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlxez.png'
    }, {
      url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9GML.png'
    }];

    // Calculate tiles
    Array(CANVAS_WIDTH / TILE_WIDTH * CANVAS_HEIGHT / TILE_HEIGHT)
      .fill()
      .forEach(function() {
        const randomNum = self.getRandomNumber(0, self.tiles.length - 1);
        const tile = self.tiles[randomNum]

        self.generateTile(tile.url, xAxes, yAxes);

        xAxes += TILE_WIDTH;

        if (xAxes === CANVAS_WIDTH) {
          xAxes = 0;
          yAxes += TILE_HEIGHT;
        }
      });
  }

  /**
   * get a random number
   * @param  {number} min 
   * @param  {number} max 
   * @return {number}     
   */
  getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  /**
   * Generate one tile
   * @param  {string} url 
   * @param  {number} x  
   * @param  {number} y     
   */
  generateTile(url, x, y) {
    let tile = new Image();

    tile.onload = () => {
      this.ctx.drawImage(tile, x, y);
    };

    tile.src = url;
  }
}


const map = new GenerateMap();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**ES5:**

```js
var GenerateMap = function() {

  var self = this;

  // canvas
  self.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  self.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var TILE_WIDTH = 100;
  var TILE_HEIGHT = 100;

  var CANVAS_WIDTH = 500;
  var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 500;

  var xAxes = 0;
  var yAxes = 0;
  var lineCount = 0;
  
  self.canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
  self.canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

  // existing tiles
  self.tiles = [{
    url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwkth.png'
  }, {
    url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlxez.png'
  }, {
    url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9GML.png'
  }];

  // Calculate tiles
  Array(CANVAS_WIDTH / TILE_WIDTH * CANVAS_HEIGHT / TILE_HEIGHT)
    .fill()
    .forEach(function() {
      var randomNum = self.getRandomNumber(0, self.tiles.length - 1);
      var tile = self.tiles[randomNum]

      self.generateTile(tile.url, xAxes, yAxes);

      xAxes += TILE_WIDTH;

      if (xAxes === CANVAS_WIDTH) {
        xAxes = 0;
        yAxes += TILE_HEIGHT;
      }
    });
}


GenerateMap.prototype.getRandomNumber = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

GenerateMap.prototype.generateTile = function(url, x, y) {
  var tile = new Image();

  tile.onload = () => {
    this.ctx.drawImage(tile, x, y);
  };

  tile.src = url;
}


var map = new GenerateMap();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: So I tried to fit this into my code and it keeps throwing me a bunch of errors...  Even in the code snippet window it won't execute properly...

Comment: Oh its written in ES6. Give me a second. I will update my post.

Comment: Bumping for the assistance in piecing together a hodgepodge solution to work off of (I needed to modify it to actually get it to work).  I'm gonna run some tests and I'll check this as the answer if I can make it do what I need it to.

Comment: I needed to make lots of modifications to get it working right, but I eventually got this to work exactly how I needed it to!  Thanks so much for your help!